# python-select unique key values from json object

Tags: python, json

I have a **json** response:

```
{
  "data": [
  {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Tom",
     "age": "24",
  },
  {
     "id": "2",
     "name": "Nick",
     "age": "45",
 },
 {
     "id": "3",
     "name": "Harry",
     "age": "18",
 },
 {
     "id": "1",
     "name": "Tom",
     "age": "29",
 }
],
 "count": 4
}
```

And i want **output** to be like this:

```
output[
{
   "id": "1",
   "name": "Tom",
   "age": "24",
},
{
   "id": "2",
   "name": "Nick",
   "age": "45",
},
{
   "id": "3",
   "name": "Harry",
   "age": "18",
}
]
```

What I want is to fetch all dictionary objects having unique names.
I know how to fetch unique names, but I want to fetch `id` and `age` too. 
There are two dictionary objects corresponding to `name` `Tom`. I want to keep one in my output.

This is the **working code to fetch uniquenames**:

```
size=len(data["data"])
uniqueNames = [];
for i in range(0,size,1):  
    if(data["data"][i]["name"] not in uniqueNames):
         uniqueNames.append(data["data"][i]["name"]); 
print uniqueNames
```

Comment: I added some code so you can also get the bad answers too.  It prints them in order.  If you could mark my answer as solution, that'd be great thanks.  If you need any more help, just comment.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you should fix your code:  Simply keep your registry of names and then add a algorithm for keeping the rest of the information.  For me, I created another array for storing the whole data object that have unique names, called returnValue.  And whenever there is a unique name, it pushes the entire data object onto returnValue.  Then, it prints it out (or returns it, if you turn it into a function).

```
returnValue = []
size=len(data["data"])
uniqueNames = []
for i in range(0,size,1):  
    if(data["data"][i]["name"] not in uniqueNames):
         uniqueNames.append(data["data"][i]["name"]) 
         returnValue.append(data["data"][i])
print returnValue
```

Because of author's question:

```
returnValue = []
badValues = []
size=len(data["data"])
uniqueNames = []
for i in range(0,size,1):  
    if(data["data"][i]["name"] not in uniqueNames):
         uniqueNames.append(data["data"][i]["name"]) 
         returnValue.append(data["data"][i])
    else:
         badValues.append(data["data"][i])
print "Good ones: " 
print returnValue
print "Bad ones: "
print badValues
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go,

```
import json
jsonFile = open('aa.json', 'r')
data = json.load(jsonFile)

size=len(data["data"])
print size
values = [];
uniqueNames = [];
for i in data["data"]:
    if(i["name"] not in uniqueNames):
         uniqueNames.append(i["name"]);
         values.append(i)
jsonFile.close()
```