# Unique values of list of json objects

Tags: python, json, unique

I have a huge list of json objects, and many of them are repeated. Those that are repeated have exactly the same values for the same keys. For example in the following list

```
[{ "name": "John", "id": 1},{ "name": "Carl", "id": 5},{ "name": "John", "id": 1}]
```

I want to get the unique objects

```
[{ "name": "John", "id": 1},{ "name": "Carl", "id": 5}]
```

I tried using the function set() but apparently it does not work with elements of type: dict.

Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42710604/4618605

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python-select unique key values from json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710604/python-select-unique-key-values-from-json-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try hashing the dictionaries before adding them to your set. To do this, simply turn the dictionary into a string.

```
d1 = { "name": "John", "id": 1}
d2 = { "name": "Carl", "id": 5}
d3 = { "name": "John", "id": 1}
s = set()

for d in [d1,d2,d3]:
    if str(d) not in s:
        s.add(str(d))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the following error in 
    s.add(d)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: My mistake, that should be `s.add(str(d))`.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to kindly mark this answer as selected if you feel it was helpful.